# Could not find class JUNIT org.junit.runner.JUnitCore

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I have test class created by framework

```
import org.selenium.MainTestCase;

public class Test01 extends MainTestCase {

  @Override
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    startSeleniumSession("RemoteWebDriver", "http://102.0.0.01:8080/hello/");
  }

  public void testMethod() throws Exception {

        session().open("/hello/request.co","");
        session().selectFrame("top_frame");
        session().type("id=lgn:username","test");
        session().type("id=lgn:password","test");
        session().click("id=lgn:submit");
        session().waitForFrameToLoad("top_frame","");
  }

  @Override
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
  }

}
```

And I have bat file

```
javac -cp .\lib\* Test01.java
java -cp .\lib\* org.junit.runner.JUnitCore Test01
```

In lib folder I have all jars and framework which generated `Test01` class for me.

When I run my bat file I got result:

JUnit version 4.10
Coul not find class: Test01
Time: 0,002
OK(0 tests)

*Structure of classes and libs is:*

Root folder - `dist`

`lib` folder(under `dist`) - where all my libs placed

In `dist` folder I have `Test01.class` and `Test01.java` and `run.bat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your current directory to the classpath with a `.`. On windows-based systems you separate folders with a `;` while on a unix-based systems you separate with a `:`.

Windows Example : `my/path/1;.` (Adds path `my/path/1` and the current directory)

Unix example: `my/path/1:.` (Adds path `my/path/1` and the current directory)